# Python: sum values of dict which keys are values in another dict

Tags: python, dictionary, dictionary-comprehension

Say that we have two dictionaries:

```
d1={'A':['a','b','c'],'B':['d','e']}
d2={'a':3,'b':1,'c':1,'d':2,'e':0}
```

And that we need to compute a third dictionary that has the same keys as `d1`, and for values the sum of the values in `d2` that correspond to those keys that are, in turn, values in`d1`.

Example:

```
d3={'A':5,'B':2}
```

where `5` is assigned to `A` because it is the sum of the values of `a`,`b`,`c`, which are assigned to `A` in `d1`.

My attempt:

```
d3={key:sum(d2[i] for i in d1[j] for j in d1.keys()) for key in d1.keys()}
```

returns:
`NameError: global name 'j' is not defined`

Sorry for the trivial question, but what am I missing here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's simpler than that if you use [`dict.items()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.items):

```
d3 = {key: sum(d2[v] for v in val) for key, val in d1.items()}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
d3 = {}
for k,v in d1.items():
     d3[k] = sum([ d2[x] for x in v ])
```

Answer (score 1):

```
d1={'A':['a','b','c'],'B':['d','e']}
d2={'a':3,'b':1,'c':1,'d':2,'e':0}

dict(zip(d1.keys(), map(lambda x:sum(d2.get(i) for i in x[1]), d1.items())))
```